# When is a null not null, when it is in Context

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is an interesting problem, when I explicitly insert a null value into the database for the column `smuId`:

```
INSERT [tblTyreHistory]
(
    [changetype], [datechanged], [fitterid],[isfitted],  
    [position], [reason],[MachineId], [rimid], [tyreid], [userid], [smuId]
)
    VALUES (1,'2014-05-19 00:00:00',86,1,1,NULL,95,NULL,5699,86,NULL)
```

The insert works as you expect. However, if I leave out the column `smuId` from the insert I get a foreign key constraint:

```
INSERT [tblTyreHistory]
(
    [changetype], [datechanged], [fitterid],[isfitted],  
    [position], [reason],[MachineId], [rimid], [tyreid], [userid]
)
    VALUES (1,'2014-05-19 00:00:00',86,1,1,NULL,95,NULL,5699,86)
```

This is causing the problem:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblTyreHistory_tblSmu". The conflict occurred in database "myDB", table "dbo.tblSmutable", column 'id'.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Likely the default value for `smuId` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly if you have a default value specified for column smuId which is not there in tblSmutable? This will cause smuId to be populated with the default value instead of NULL and will give error.